# Separate functions in partial derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Is it true that:
$$
\dfrac{\partial f(x)g(y)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{d f(x)}{d x}g(y)
$$

I have a feeling it is (just consider $g(y)$ to be a constant in the derivative), but I'm not very confident in this argument.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some attempts of proof.

Comment: Just apply the Product Rule;  $$\dfrac{\partial f(x)g(y)}{\partial x}= f(x)\cdot\dfrac{\partial g(y)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\cdot g(y)$$